# Error in HCatRecord

Tags: java, hadoop, hcatalog

I am going through a POC in which i need to write the MRUnit test cases for my mapper which uses a input format as Hcatalog

```
    public class MapClass extends
    Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord, Text, Text> {
```

But i am facing issues at these lines of code

```
   HCatRecord record = new HCatRecord();
   record.set(0, "0");
   record.set(1, "0");


   mapDriver.withInput(new LongWritable(), record)
            .withOutput(new Text("sunday"), new Text(""))
            .runTest();
```

Error::
mapDriver.withInput(new LongWritable(), record) throws java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.MRScoringUnitTest$1.()

Answer (score 0):

Many of the Custom file Input/Output formats doesn't work with MRUnit. Even HCatInputFormat doesn't work with MRUnit. HCatlog APIs need a working hive metastore to access tables over mapreduce.

When your code has any custom map reduce components like Comparators, Partitioners or Input/Output formats MRUnit cannot be used for unit testing.

Miniclusters can be used for testing the same.

https://github.com/apache/hcatalog/blob/branch-0.1/src/test/org/apache/hcatalog/mapreduce/HCatMapReduceTest.java